# Averge of the mean field theory hamiltoninan

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

So I am trying to solve a problem where I have to calculate E and I am given the hamiltonian so I can compute the averge of H which is then E.

H is defined as: $ H = -J*d*m\sum{\sigma_i} + \frac{JdNm^2}{2}$

Here J is a constant d is also a constant, N is number of particles so also a constant. m is magnetisation and sigma is in which direction the spin is pointing. If it points up it is +1 and if it points down it is -1. How should I do to calculate this?

Answer (score 0):

Taking average on both sides of the equation we get:

$<H> = -Jdm<\sum \sigma_i> + \frac{JdNm^2}{2}$

By definition $m = \frac{<\sum \sigma_i>}{N}$. Substituting it in the above equation we get:

$<H> = -\frac{JdNm^2}{2}$

This is the average energy.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I wonder, is there any physics in thinking about what the averge of m would be? I mean m is already an averge of spins, but if we have an ensamble of different m what would be the averge m? Does it make any sense even asking such question?

Comment: It depends on the probability of the spin pointing up or down. If the probability of pointing up is $p$ then $m = 2p-1$. In your question you have not given that information. So I left the answer in terms of $m$.